# UI is updating without notifyListeners(). why?

Tags: flutter, dart, user-interface

I am learning provider package. there is a function notifyListeners() which need to update UI. I have a list in which i am adding new value through TextField and by adding new value my UI is updating according without using notifylistners(). My question is why UI is updating without notifylistners(). Is there any other case in which a required notifylistners() to update the screen.

Here is my code:

```
   class StudentController with ChangeNotifier{
    
      var studentList = [
        Student('Ali', 'Karachi', 23),
        Student('Rizwan', 'Islamabad', 33),
      ];
    
      addStudent(newname, newage, newcity){
       var student = Student(newname,newage,newcity);
       studentList.add(student);
       // notifyListeners();
      }
    }

    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    
        final students  = Provider.of<StudentController>(context).studentList;
    
        return Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            backgroundColor: Colors.white,
            foregroundColor: colorGreen,
            title: titleRow,
            centerTitle: true,
          ),
          body: ListView.builder(
            itemCount: students.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
             return ListTile(
               leading: Text('${students[index].name}'),
             );
            }
          ),
        );

                

    child: TextButton(
                      onPressed: (){
    
                        var name = nameController.text;
                        var city = cityController.text;
                        var age = ageController.text;
                        Provider.of<StudentController>(context, listen: false).addStudent(name, city, int.parse(age));
                        Get.to(StudentView());
    
    
                        
                      },

class Student{
  late String name;
  late String city;
  late int age;

  Student(this.name, this.city, this.age);

}
```

Comment: Can you separate your model class and widget

Comment: There might be some parent code that is rebuilding the UI. This code seems fine